# Magento Controller Does not Render

Tags: magento-1.8

My Baobaz_Arithmetic.xml file  app/etc/modules/Baobaz_Arithmetic.xml  is below:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Baobaz_Arithmetic>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
           </Baobaz_Arithmetic>
      </modules>
  </config>
```

Config file :: code/local/Baobaz/Arithmetic/etc/config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Baobaz_Arithmetic>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Baobaz_Arithmetic>
        </modules>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <arithmetic> <!-- Any Name is fine as long as there is no conflict -->
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Baobaz_Arithmetic</module>  <!-- Name of the module -->
                        <frontName>arithmetic</frontName>
                    </args>
                </arithmetic>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

My Controller is here:   code/local/Baobaz/Arithmetic/controller/IndexController.php

```
   class Baobaz_Arithmetic_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

        public function indexAction() {

            echo 'Hello Index!';

        }

    }
```

Error :: 404 page not found. 
I can see it on configuration >> advance; and it is enabled. 
Could anybody please help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@m82a,there path issue in contollers folder ,it `should  be controllers from contoller`

Comment: Did you mean folder name :: code/local/Baobaz/Arithmetic/controller/IndexController.php  to code/local/Baobaz/Arithmetic/controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: ya..right.......